# Visual Basic in excel drop down list population based on a key

Tags: vba, excel

I have been attempting to create a drop down list on a worksheet that populates based on the entry in a different cell i.e

> ```
> ws1------------------------------- 
> |numbers|dropdowns               |  
> |123    |->123 associations list |     
> |456    |->456 associations list |    
> ----------------------------------
>
> ws2----------------------
> |123    | tttttt | 9000 |  
> |123    | kkkkkk | 8000 |  
> |123    | hhhhhh | 7000 |  
> |456    | yyyyyy | 6000 |  
> |456    | uuuuuu | 5000 | 
> -------------------------
> ```

so that when 123 or 456 is typed into the numbers cell, the drop down list populates from the associated cells in ws2 i.e

"typed by user"| "auto populates list"
|456           | yyyyyy-6000      |
- uuuuuu-5000

then the user can select yyyyyy or uuuuuu and the cell would populate with the character cell value from the list selection.

Comment: this may help: http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dependent-drop-down-lists.html

Comment: excellent suggestion @ScottHoltzman and that is what im looking for but the database im working with is rather large and the data is already oriented vertically, this method would require me to make 50+ ranges and copy a few thousand data points over. As well as defeat the scalability  of the program. you got my hopes up scott!

Comment: I've got a similar application that uses the on change event for the sheet to detect a change in the first pick list, then dynamically fills the range that is the source for the second pick list and so on (three deep).  The ranges for the pick lists are in an unused area of one of the sheets.  I could just as well be a hidden sheet.  Is this what you have in mind?

Comment: @Hrothgar that is a fix but i dont want to use the pick list application to populate the list. this creates a specific fix to the current work book and im more trying to find a generalized fix, as this workbook will be used in different locations with different values and subvalues so i cant populate the list with fixed cell ranges. but if the ranges update dynamically then yes this is what im looking for!

Comment: thanks for reformatting my question @Rook, i have solved it, but im very unhappy about the runtime of the actual lookup function im using its also not the prettiest way of doing it but i use a nested index function to find the values associated with the the "numbers" im looking at then i use a multiple value return vlookup function to find the second column items then a normal vlookup to find the third column items then concat the second and third items, then use the .split function to in a loop in vba to split the second and third items so the cell only populates with the value desired

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version of my pick list app.

in the change event for the worksheet where you enter the numbers:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A5")) Is Nothing Then Fill_X_list (Me.Range("A5"))
End Sub
```

In the code module:

```
Sub Fill_X_list(myX As String)
Dim locx As Long, YBottom As Long
Dim listcounter As Long
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
listcounter = 2
Sheets("Lists").Range("A:Z").ClearContents
Sheets("Lists").Range("A1") = myX
Sheets("WS1").Range("C5") = "All Values"
YBottom = Sheets("WS2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For locx = 1 To YBottom
    If Sheets("WS2").Cells(locx, 1) = myX Then
        Sheets("lists").Cells(listcounter, 1) = Sheets("WS2").Cells(locx, 2) & "-" & Sheets("WS2").Cells(locx, 3)
        listcounter = listcounter + 1
    End If
Next locx

Sheets("Lists").Range("A2:A" & Sheets("lists").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Name = "YList"
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The cell where you enter the '123' should be the range in the on change event (i.e A5).  The range sheets ("lists").cells ("A2:A3") should be named "YList."  the size of the range will change when the sub runs.

The cell where the pick list is, should have validation "list" with source = YList.

I think that's it.  If I missed anything let me know.  I have a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Being that the second column needs to find multiple values associated with a single repeated value from the fist column i use this function

```
=INDEX(ASP!$D2:$D$2048,SMALL _
(INDEX((Sheet1!AH$2=ASP!$A2:$A$2048)* 
(MATCH(ROW(ASP!$A2:$A$2048),ROW(ASP!$A2:$A$2048)))+ _
(Sheet1!AH$2<>ASP!$A2:$A$2048)*2048,0,0),ROW($A1)))
```

and drag it down for a reasonable amount of rows based on the program limitations. This is a nasty function that can take seconds to complete based on the range of cells being looked at.
i.e if you just use "ASP!A:A" instead of  "ASP!A2:A2028" this ends up running n^2 indexing calls and takes forever.

Then i use

```
=VLOOKUP(AI2,ASP!$D:$G,4,0)
```

to populate the next set of columns based on what the first set finds

Then i use

```
=IFERROR(CONCATENATE(AI2,"|",AJ2),"")
```

to put the second and third columns together so that both data points are present when the list dropdown is used.

after this i just use data validation lists and populate them with the values in the last column, using the IFERROR to make the cells in the list that dont have any data points related to them appear blank. and i use an on_change event to go through the currently changed value in the list column to split the concat up and only populate the cell with the desired value.

The point of this is so that a user will not have to look through multiple pages of the excel workbook to select the appropriate data point to fill in on a submission page they can just type in the initially desired category then the list will show available options and the amount that these options are present in.